# Error hosting WCF service in windows

Tags: wcf, windows-services

I am getting the following error when trying to host my WCF service in windows on the server. I am installing it using InstallUtil.exe.
I hosted the same service on my local system. It worked perfectly fine. But not working when trying on the server.

**Installing assembly 'D:\wwwroot\ABCServices\ABC.servicehost.exe'.
    Affected parameters are: 
    assemblypath = D:\wwwroot\CareScoutServices\ABC.servicehost.exe
    logfile = D:\wwwroot\ABCServices\ABC.servicehost.InstallLog
    logtoconsole = 
    Unable to create an instance of the ABC.ServiceHost.ProjectInstaller installer type.
    System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
    The inner exception System.NullReferenceException was thrown with the following error     message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object..
    Rolling back assembly 'D:\wwwroot\ABCServices\ABC.servicehost.exe'.
    Affected parameters are:
    assemblypath = D:\wwwroot\ABCServices\ABC.servicehost.exe
    logfile = D:\wwwroot\ABCServices\ABC.servicehost.InstallLog
    logtoconsole = 
    Unable to create an instance of the ABC.ServiceHost.ProjectInstaller installer type.
    System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of     an invocation.
    The inner exception System.NullReferenceException was thrown with the following error     message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object..**

Can someone please help resolve this error.

Comment: Is D: your network drive?

Comment: @PM. No D:is not my network drive. It is a local drive.

Comment: I am not sure, but try to move it to your primary drive and then try. You can give it a try.

Comment: I tried doing the same. But no luck. Still throws the same error.

Comment: By seeing the error "Unable to create an instance of the ABC.ServiceHost.ProjectInstaller installer type", this seems some kind of access issue. Please make sure you are using user with correct rights on the server.

Comment: I do have the Local Admin access on the server. Is there a way to verify if i have the sufficient access?

Comment: Check the users/groups and ensure that user is in Admin group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basic but try running the InstallUtil as an administrator.